# Como usar shape como drawable em imagespan

Tags: android

Tenho um imageSpan, porem ele só funciona com imagens, quando tento usar um shape o local da imagem fica como se n tivesse imagem alguma, porem tambem não apresenta nenhum erro.

```
       String text = exercicios.get(0).getPergunta();
    Log.i(TAG, exercicios.get(0).getPergunta());
    //String text = "texto # texto";

    //Posição onde colocar a imegem(posição da marca)
    int imagePos = text.indexOf("#");

    //Criar um SpannableString do texto
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);

    //Obter o drawable a inserir
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shapepergunta);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0,drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

    //Criar um ImageSpan do drawable
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    //Inserir a imagem(ImageSpan) no texto(SpannableString)
    spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan,imagePos,imagePos+1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    //Atribuir o texto com a imagem ao TextView
    txvpergunta.setText(spannableString);
```

Shape:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:radius="14dp"
/>
<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerColor="#198CFF"
android:startColor="#449DEF"
android:endColor="#2F6699"
android:type="linear"
/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="1dp"
android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Coloque o xml do shape.

Comment: coloquei @ramaral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma como a *shape* está declarada ela não tem dimensões.

Quando ela é usada como *background* ou *foreground* de outra *view* não tem problema, já que ela se ajusta à dimensão da view.

Quando usada como *span* isso não se verifica. Assim tem de definir as sua dimensões.

Pode fazê-lo de duas formas:

- Incluindo o atributo `size` no xml:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle" >
      <size
          android:width="32dp"
          android:height="16dp"/>
      <corners
          android:radius="14dp"/>
      <gradient
          android:angle="45"
          android:centerX="35%"
          android:centerColor="#198CFF"
          android:startColor="#449DEF"
          android:endColor="#2F6699"
          android:type="linear"/>
      <padding
          android:left="0dp"
          android:top="0dp"
          android:right="0dp"
          android:bottom="0dp"/>
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#878787"/>
  </shape>
  ```
- No java através de `setBounds()`:

  ```
  //Obter o drawable a inserir
  Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shapepergunta);
  drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 64, 32);
  ```

Comment: Consegui fazer usando setbounds, direto no xml, não ficou bem alinhado verticalmente, uma duvida que fiquei é que o drawable some quando  quando o valor bottom do setbound é menor que 3

Comment: Suponho que seja por ser pequeno demais para ser representado.